# How to get rid of errors "jitter buffer full" in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, rtsp, rtp

How to get rid of errors `jitter buffer full` ?
I use ffmpeg from one of the latest snapshots.
`ffmpeg version N-90078-gf611fef Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers`

The problem is that from the camera on rtsp there is such a stream:
http://ibb.co/fmckCc
It is not possible to fix this from the camera side.

I accept it like this:

```
ffmpeg \
-strict experimental \
-fflags + genpts \
-fflags + latm \
-seek2any 1 \
-avoid_negative_ts + make_zero \
-max_delay 5000000 \
-rtsp_transport udp \
-i rtsp: // admin: @ 192.168.87.21: 554/0? .sdp \
-map 0 \
-r 15 \
-c: v copy \
-an \
-f mpegts udp: //239.0.0.1: 1234? ttl = 1? pkt_size = 1316
```

I later start to get errors from time to time

```
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] jitter buffer full
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] RTP: missed 1 packets
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] jitter buffer full
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] RTP: missed 1 packets
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] jitter buffer full
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] RTP: missed 2 packets
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] jitter buffer full
[rtsp @ 0x154d180] RTP: missed 4 packets
```

because of this the picture crumbles.

I increased the udp buffer in the linux kernel settings:

```
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 8388608 12582912 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 8388608
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 8388608
```

It did not solve my problem.
Tell me, how can you deal with such errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try to lower max_delay or increase jitter buffer. When you set max_delay for time longer than packets count your jitter buffer can handle, you will get buffer full error, and therefore packets will be lost.